# Connect to PostgreSQL DB with 'public' schema

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, database-connection

How do I connect to the PostgreSQL database with the following connection info?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

```
POSTGRES_DIALECT = 'postgresql'
POSTGRES_SERVER = 'server'
POSTGRES_DBNAME = 'db'
POSTGRES_SCHEMA = 'public' 
POSTGRES_USERNAME = 'user' 
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = 'password'

postgres_str = ('{dialect}://{username}:{password}@{server}:{schema}/{dbname}'.format(
                    dialect=POSTGRES_PROVIDER,
                    server=POSTGRES_SERVER,
                    dbname=POSTGRES_DBNAME,
                    schema=POSTGRES_SCHEMA,
                    username=POSTGRES_USERNAME,
                    password=POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                ))
# Create the connection
cnx = create_engine(postgres_str)
```

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'public'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subbing in "schema" where the port belongs.  'public' is not a valid port number.

Comment: In the connection info that was sent to me there's 'Schema: public', I have to use it

Comment: Yes, but you don't specify the schema in the connection string.

Comment: And where should I specify the scheme?